# Are there any real world open source backbone.js web applications using .net framework (preferably asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

Are there any open source asp.net web applications which are using backbone.js and preferably those that have composite views and models being shared among views.

It will be a good to have the source code of some real world applications to understand backbone more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the [EpicWinHosting](http://epicwinhosting.com/) web is real world it is not open source.

However they have given a very [detailed blog](http://www.codethinked.com/building-epic-win-with-backbone-js) with code examples which might be what you are looking for.

Have you seen the [Todo List app on github](https://github.com/kalpers/Todo-App--Backbone.js-and-ASP.Net-MVC)?

Comment: thanks for your reply..I had gone through the blog earlier.The problem with that blog is there is not much code in it and also it shows the usage of backbone.controller which is not used anymore

Comment: @CrazyNooB updated answer with another which is open source but not really real world ;)